# Get-AzAksVersion trying to get the default version

Tags: kubernetes, version, azure-aks, azure-powershell

Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($*.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.23.12') -and ($*.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion}
[[image: output]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Mvl.png)
why its giving downgrade version '1.23.8' if my condition is greaterthan '1.23.12'

Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($*.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.23.8') -and ($*.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion}
[image: output]
if my condition is greater than '1.23.8' output getting is 1.24.3, 1.24.6 not getting default version '1.23.12'. Hope can help me with a problem trying to execute a script block

Answer (score 0):

***I checked the same in my environment with the command you used***

```
Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.23.12') -and ($.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion}
```

Its giving the same output , and its correct .

If I checked the lower versions than **1.23.8**  , I can see 1.23.12  which is obviously less that that.

*Command:*

```
Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -lt '1.23.8') -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion}
```

***Output:***

```
1.22.11
1.22.15
1.23.12
```

[image]

Here it is needed to observe that it is **one** **two** after dot(.) and ***not twelve*** >12 (  1.23.12 )

**And version 1.23.8 is greater than 1.23.12**

Checked the same for greater than 1.23.32

[image]

Comment: Thanks@kavya Saraboju  -Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.23.12') -and ($.IsPreview -ne 'True')} | foreach {$_.OrchestratorVersion} **output:** 1.23.8, 1.24.3, 1.24.6 is 1.23.8 is gt 1.23.12? your getting same output

Comment: yes ! i have added snap  and please note that  1.23.8 is greater than 1.23.12